# How to best convert Map<String,Foo> to Map<MyEnum,Foo> in a wrapper

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, hashmap, code-organization

Update, adding the question from the comments:

> what's the best way to get the Map into Map where
>   Foo is an Enum. it just seems awfully complicated when, conceptually,
>   not a complex idea.

This code functions, it's part of a simple [MUD client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mud_client).  The basic idea is that `Monitor` holds data (hit points, etc) which will be displayed to the user during game play, perhaps in a secondary `JPanel`; something along those lines.  The possible values for this report are in the `Attribs` as an `Enum`.

Before going too far down that path, when I look at the `Monitor` class and what it takes to create a single instance it seems more than a little verbose.

If I move `convertToEnumEntry` out of `Monitor` then the class won't work.  So, the class can't get smaller, I don't think.  Is there a pattern I could use (or use better)?

Everything in this class rests on the assumption  that if `convertToEnumEntry` returns a null reference to a `Map.Entry` to then get the one, specific `String` which doesn't fit in `Attribs`:

`enemy = stringEntry.getKey();`

Unlike the other keys, the enemy can be any `String`.  The other keys are limited to the `Enum` values of `Attribs` (attributes).

```
public class Monitor {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Monitor.class.getName());
    private Map<Attribs, Ratio> mapOfAttributes = new HashMap<>();
    private String enemy = null;

    private Monitor() {
    }

    public Monitor(Map<String, Ratio> mapStringToRatio) {
        init(mapStringToRatio);
    }

    private void init(Map<String, Ratio> mapStringToRatio) {
        SimpleEntry<Attribs, Ratio> attribsEntry = null;
        for (Entry<String, Ratio> stringEntry : mapStringToRatio.entrySet()) {
            attribsEntry = null;
            attribsEntry = convertToEnumEntry(stringEntry);
            if (attribsEntry != null) {
                mapOfAttributes.put(attribsEntry.getKey(), attribsEntry.getValue());
            } else {
                enemy = stringEntry.getKey();     //assumes key is enemy value
                mapOfAttributes.put(Attribs.ENEMY, stringEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    private SimpleEntry<Attribs, Ratio> convertToEnumEntry(Entry<String, Ratio> stringEntry) {
        Ratio ratio = stringEntry.getValue();
        SimpleEntry<Attribs, Ratio> attribEntry = null;
        for (Attribs attribute : Attribs.values()) {
            if (stringEntry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(attribute.name())) {
                attribEntry = new HashMap.SimpleEntry<>(attribute, ratio);
            }
        }
        return attribEntry;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("\nfighting\t\t" + enemy + "\n");
        for (Map.Entry<Attribs, Ratio> e : mapOfAttributes.entrySet()) {
            sb.append("\n");
            sb.append(e.getKey().name());
            sb.append("\t");
            sb.append(e.getValue().toString());
        }
        sb.append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

It's tempting to either cram everything into either one class to parse and build the `Map`, or put everything into `Monitor`.  Currently, `RegexMapBuilder` is a sort of middle ground, because it does most of the hard work, but doesn't quite build a complete `Monitor` on its own:

```
public class RegexMapBuilder {

    public static Map<String, Ratio> stringToRatiosMap(String input) {
        Map<String, Ratio> mapOfStringsToRatios = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> strings = stringMap(input);
        Pattern fraction = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)/(\\d+)");
        Pattern wholeNumber = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        Pattern percent = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)%");
        Matcher matcher;
        int numerator, denominator;
        Ratio ratio = null;             //need numerator and denominator values
        for (Entry<String, String> e : strings.entrySet()) {
            matcher = wholeNumber.matcher(e.getValue());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                denominator = 1;
                ratio = new Ratio(numerator, denominator);
            }
            matcher = fraction.matcher(e.getValue());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                denominator = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
                ratio = new Ratio(numerator, denominator);
            }
            matcher = percent.matcher(e.getValue());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                denominator = 100;
                ratio = new Ratio(numerator, denominator);
            }
            mapOfStringsToRatios.put(e.getKey(), ratio);
        }
        return mapOfStringsToRatios;
    }

    private static Map<String, String> stringMap(String input) {
        Map<String, String> strings = new HashMap<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): +(\\S+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            strings.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
        return strings;
    }
}
```

For brevity, I omitted the `Enum`, but `Attribs` is just a list of a few attributes which this report prints.  The only tricky part is that there's one value which isn't really an Enum type.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: what's the best way to get the Map<String,Bar> into Map<Foo,Bar> where Foo is an Enum.  it just seems awfully complicated when, conceptually, not a complex idea.

Comment: Why not just use `Attribs attr = Attribs.valueOf(stringValue.toUpperCase());` for the `String -> Attribs` algorithm?

Comment: `stringValue` **might** be an `Attrib`, but not necessarily.  There are about five `Attrib` values, and then a sixth which is just a `String` and this variable can be anything.  So it's almost, but not, an `enum'.

Answer (score 1):

I think [java.util.EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) may be what you're looking for. You can use [Enum#valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) to look up the enum value from the given String, like Sam Yonnou mentioned.